# Custom build System.Security Monotouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to use System.Security.Cryptography.XML in an Ios and Android project.

Is it possible to build a custom System.Security from sources for using in monotouch and monodroid? Where is an example?

Answer (score 0):

The types inside the [System.Security.Cryptography.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace are part of `System.Security.dll` (not `System.Xml.dll`).

While not shipped with Xamarin.iOS (or Xamarin.Android) it should be possible (and not too hard) to use Mono source code and build this assembly against the mobile profile that ships with them.

However I'm not aware of anyone who did it and made that source (or binary) public.